# Variable names disappear when using summarytools::descr() with by() in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, summarytools

The descr() function from R-package *summarytools* generates common central tendency statistics and measures of dispersion for numerical data in R.

When I use descr() with by() in a **Shiny app**, names of variable (features) contained in the data disappear and not displayed. Instead, the names  are replaced by Var1, Var2, Var3 etc.

I do not really understand why the names disappear when I implement these code in the Shiny app (see below). 
Any idea?

```
# Install packages
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("ALL")
biocLite("Biobase")
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('dcomtois/summarytools')

# Load packages
library(summarytools)
library(Biobase)
library(ALL) 

# Shiny Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$summaryTable <- renderUI({
    #-- Load the ALL data
    data(ALL)  
    #-- Subset
    eset_object <- ALL [1:3,] # choose only 3 variables 
    #-- The group of interest 
    eset_groups <-"BT"
    # print(rownames (eset_object)) # print variable names
    ALL_stats_by_BT <- by(data = as.data.frame(t(exprs(eset_object))), 
                          INDICES = (pData(eset_object)[,eset_groups]), 
                          FUN = descr, stats ="all", 
                          transpose = TRUE)

    view(ALL_stats_by_BT,
         method = 'render',
         omit.headings = FALSE,
         bootstrap.css = FALSE)
  })
}

# Shiny UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = "dfSummary.css",
                fluidRow(
                  uiOutput("summaryTable")
                )
)

# Lauch
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headings cause problems, so you need to use:

```
view(ALL_stats_by_BT,
        method = 'render',
        omit.headings = TRUE, # not FALSE
        bootstrap.css = FALSE)
```

Also, install the latest version from gitHub (commited today) to have all the groups displayed (that was an issue with `descr()` in versions < 0.8.7)

`devtools::install_github("dcomtois/summarytools")`

**EDIT**

I looked into it a bit more, and found that while this will work (I'm using a sample data frame for simplification)...

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  library(summarytools)

  output$summaryTable <- renderUI({

    data(exams)

    stats_by_gender <- by(data = exams[,3:4],
                          INDICES = exams$gender, 
                          FUN = descr, stats ="all", 
                          transpose = TRUE)

    view(stats_by_gender,
         method = 'render',
         bootstrap.css = FALSE)

  })
}
```

... This doesn't (meaning the variable names are lost):

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  library(summarytools)

  output$summaryTable <- renderUI({

    data(exams)

    # this time using a temporary subsetted object     
    dat <- exams[,3:4]    

    stats_by_gender <- by(data = dat,
                          INDICES = exams$gender, 
                          FUN = descr, stats ="all", 
                          transpose = TRUE)

    view(stats_by_gender,
         method = 'render',
         bootstrap.css = FALSE)

  })
}
```

It has to do with the way *summarytools* retrieves object names, I'll need to look further into it.

Comment: I have followed your instruction but I still have the same issue! Have you had the chance to run my example app?

Comment: Ok I see a hint but have no solution yet... If you load into memory (Global Env) the `eset_object`, do you see the variable names?

Comment: Yes, if one reads in the data as Global variable: eset_object <<- ALL [1:3,], the variable names will be displayed. But, as you know, "global variables are evil", why I would like to avoid global variables!  Any solution?

Comment: For now my only advice is to do a pact with the devil until further notice ;). I'll be away for the next month or so and I won't have much time to devote to summarytools. But if someone wants to fork it and give it a shot, by all means do it! You can also create an issue on the project's page, and I can add the tag "help wanted" for it.

Comment: I opened this issue on the project's page!

Comment: OK! I have now looked further into it and found that the problem occurs due to this line: rownames(output)[i] <- paste0("Var",i). If you replace this line with rownames(output)[i] <- paste0(colnames(x.df)[i]) the problem is solved! What do you think?

Comment: I did something along those lines, it's in the dev-current branch now but will be part of next release. For more details, see https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools/issues/26